# Default gconf and dconf for all Users

Tags: gconf, dconf

I am trying to find a way to set the default gconf and dconf settings for all users. I know in the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` has xml files for the settings. I Changed the settings in the xml files with root and created a new user and the settings did not transfer. Under `/etc/skel` does not have any local user settings. I want default gtk theme, fonts for all users. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't edit those files directly. Even if you did get it to work, chances are all of your work would be undone as soon as an upgrade happened. So instead, use override files.

In that same directory (/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas), make a file. The file name must end in ".gschema.override".

In there, specify your defaults. For example, to set the defaults for indicator-multiload, it's something along the lines of:

```
[de.mh21.indicator.multiload]
speed=2000
size=20
view-memload=true
```

There's a pretty good explanation of how to do this, and why it's done this way here:
http://www.burtonini.com/blog/computers/gsettings-override-2011-07-04-15-45

Unfortunately it seems you can't make the settings mandatory at the moment (locks don't seem to work in Ubuntu)